# Allow pull in repository but block cloning for Apache served repository

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have a workflow where I need to allow users to be able to pull new changes from the Apache hosted mercurial repository but prevent them from doing a fresh clone.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks

- Using hgweb.wsgi to serve the repository using an apache vhost (workarounds accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just publish bundles via regular HTTP and allow users to download and apply those. See `hg help bundle`:

```
Generate a compressed changegroup file collecting changesets not known to
be in another repository.

The bundle file can then be transferred using conventional means and
applied to another repository with the unbundle or pull command. This is
useful when direct push and pull are not available or when exporting an
entire repository is undesirable.

Applying bundles preserves all changeset contents including permissions,
copy/rename information, and revision history.
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also allow the user to effectively clone by creating a new repo and applying all the bundles?

Comment: Accepting this answer as the historical bundles can be removed so that only the latest bundles are available

Answer (score 2):

A `clone` is just an `init` followed by a `pull`, so you can't stop cloning w/o also breaking pull.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be true...however, the answer below is closer to a workaround

Comment: Definitely.  You should edit your question so that it's broad enough to include that as an actual answers.  As written putting .bundle files up is no longer a "hgweb.wsgi" hosted repository.

Comment: Updating question to allow for workaround explicitly though any workarounds are always welcome. Had already upvoted your answer as a way of giving credit but with your expert score I doubt that matters to you by now :) cheers

Comment: Yeah, I'm not worried about the points (but thanks) I'm just working to make sure a search always finds prior good questions